# How I can edit my enterprise wiki custom page layout template to include MetadataNavTree.ascx control

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013

I have define a metadata navigation based on term store, but the navigation tree show up for one time only and then it disappear. and this seems to be a common problem when defining metadata navigation with enterprise Wikis as mentioned in this link:-

http://markuspersson.wordpress.com/2012/01/19/add-metadata-navigation-on-custom-page-layouts/

And as the above link suggest is that I have to manually reference the MetadataNavTree.ascx. But I am unable to figure out how I can add this reference to my Enterprise Wiki site and it’s sub sites?